# AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData deprecated

Tags: ios, ios7, audiosession

In an app of mine I have the following code:

```
AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData(routeChangeID,cvcHandleRouteChange,(__bridge void *)(self));
```

I don’t see any problem with it, it has been working for a while and still works.

But I now get this warning:

> …./MyViewController.m:1055:9:
>   'AudioSessionRemovePropertyListenerWithUserData' is deprecated: first
>   deprecated in iOS 7.0

What am I supposed to do to make the compiler happy and get rid of the message?
Even after browsing the net for a while I haven’t found any clear answer, for a way to replace this “deprecated code”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW71) instead, to replace the deprecated AudioSession APIs.